# Cycling Banners with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to Cycle couple of banner images using Javascript.
Below is the Code that I tried.  Does anybody know why I cannot get this to work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  --->Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>Contact Page</title>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
      <!--- Hide Script from Old Browsers 

      adImages1 = new Array("http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png","http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png","http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png")
      adImages2 = new Array("http://www.triadsearchmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/web-design-banner.jpg","http://www.triadsearchmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/web-design-banner.jpg")
      thisAd1 = 0
      thisAd2 = 0
      imgCt1 = adImages1.length
      imgCt2 = adImages2.length
      function rotate() {
      if (document.images) {
      thisAd1++
      if (thisAd1 == imgCt1) {
      thisAd1 = 0
      }
      document.adBanner1.src=adImages1 [thisAd1]
      thisAd2++
      if (thisAd2 == imgCt2) {
      thisAd2 = 0
      }
      document.adBanner2.src=adImages2
      [thisAd2]
      
      setTimeout("rotate()", 3 *  1000)
      
      }
      }
      
      // End hiding script from old browsers -->
      </script>script>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onload="rotate()">
      <center>
        
    
      <img src="http://www.triadsearchmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/web-design-banner.jpg" width ="400" height="75" name="adBanner1" vspace="10" alt="Ad Banner 1" /> <br/>
        <img src="http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png" width ="400" height="75" name="adBanner1" vspace="10" alt="Ad Banner 1" />
        </center>
        </body>
        <html>
```

Comment: Maybe use setInterval instead of setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were re-using the `adBanner1` name. In the code below I've:

- Changed the name on the 2nd img to `adBanner2`
- Cleaned up some incorrect extra characters in the DOCTYPE tag and at the end of the script block

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Contact Page</title>
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--- Hide Script from Old Browsers 

    adImages1 = new Array("http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png", "http://www.triadsearchmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/web-design-banner.jpg", "http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png")
    adImages2 = new Array("http://www.triadsearchmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/web-design-banner.jpg", "http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png")
    thisAd1 = 0
    thisAd2 = 0
    imgCt1 = adImages1.length
    imgCt2 = adImages2.length

    function rotate() {
      if (document.images) {
        thisAd1++
        if (thisAd1 == imgCt1) {
          thisAd1 = 0
        }
        document.adBanner1.src = adImages1[thisAd1]
        thisAd2++
        if (thisAd2 == imgCt2) {
          thisAd2 = 0
        }
        document.adBanner2.src = adImages2[thisAd2]

        setTimeout("rotate()", 3 * 1000)

      }
    }

    // End hiding script from old browsers -->
  </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onload="rotate()">
  <center>
    <img src="http://www.triadsearchmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/web-design-banner.jpg" width="400" height="75" name="adBanner1" vspace="10" alt="Ad Banner 1" /> <br/>
    <img src="http://www.rmar.in/images/service/web3.png" width="400" height="75" name="adBanner2" vspace="10" alt="Ad Banner 2" />
  </center>
</body>
<html>
```